# Primefaces 4 panels on a dashboard is not resizing

Tags: primefaces, draggable, resizable, panels

I am trying to create a dashboard with draggable and resizable panels with Primefaces. When I add the resizable to the panels it is not working. If I use it outside the dashboard it is working fine. Can you any one please help me how to add resizable to panel on a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

resizable panels in dashboard are not tested or supported yet.